# Compare DataTable Column Value with Enum in Row Filter C#

Tags: c#, enums, dataview, rowfilter

I have a Datatable which I want to filter using DataView. The filter condition is based on an Enum value and datatable column value which is string. Below is what I am trying to do

```
DataView dv = data.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "Status =" + Enum.Valid;
```

As the status column is string, the row filter won't work. I tried taking the "Status" column as of "Enum" but still it does not work.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Enum.Valid.ToString ()

Answer (score 0):

from DataView.Filter documentation: "See the Expression property of the DataColumn class for more information"

from [DataColumn.Expression Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

> For columns that contain enumeration values, cast the value to an integer data type. For example:
>   "EnumColumn = 5"

Comment: OP wrote that the datatable column type is string

Answer (score 0):

If the string values in the `Status` column are the identifier names of the enum members, then you can do a string comparison:

```
var dv = data.DefaultView;
var enumValueAsString = Enum.Valid.ToString();
dv.RowFilter = $"Status = '{enumValueAsString}'";
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When you create an expression for a filter, enclose strings with single quotation marks

If on the other hand, the values in the `Status` column are of the `Enum` type, then you need to do a numeric comparison:

```
var dv = data.DefaultView;
var enumValueAsInt = (int)Enum.Valid;
dv.RowFilter = $"Status = {enumValueAsInt}";
```

Comment: This gives me an exception that "=" operator can not be used between string and enum type

Comment: In this case I doubt that the assertion "the Status column is string" (System.String) is true.

Comment: Now I changed the "Status" column to be of type "Enum".

Answer (score 0):

So it worked for me like this without using DataView

```
 var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.Field<IfmEqcStatus>("Status") == Enum.Valid);
```